# How do you draw a rectangle in OnShape?

Tags: onshape

I am trying to use OnShape (a CAD tool)

I can't see an option to draw a rectangle

[image]

I found a tutorial but it has options I don't have

[image]

--

So the screenshot from the video above, shows an option to draw a rectangle, but I can't see one when I look at my interface.

Where is the option?